# Why doesn't PySpark's fillna() method support list types as replacement values?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I recently encountered a limitation when trying to use PySpark's fillna()([official doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.fillna)) function where I was unable to use a list as a replacement value for null entries in my DataFrame. Can someone help me understand why fillna() doesn't support list types for replacement values? I'm assuming this may have something to do with PySpark aligning with SQL semantics, where an empty list isn't a valid replacement for NULL, but I would appreciate more insight into this aspect, if possible.

I tried `df.fillna(F.array(), subset=column_names)` in PySpark to replace null values with an empty list, but this resulted in a `TypeError: value should be a float, int, string, bool or dict`. I understand that PySpark doesn't support list types in the `fillna()` function. As a workaround, I was able to use the `when()` and `otherwise()` functions to get the desired result:

```py
for column_name in column_names:
    df = df.withColumn(column_name, F.when(F.col(column_name).isNull(), F.array()).otherwise(F.col(column_name)))
```

I'd like to understand further why list types are not supported in `fillna()`. Moreover, is there a more efficient way to perform this operation, especially when dealing with a large number of columns?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a limitation in Spark. Maybe a good candidate for a PR.

## Solution

It basically casts the field to string, applies na.fill and then casts to the original type.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, from_json

# Type of your array field
type_=ArrayType(IntegerType(), True)
# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()

# Create a sample DataFrame with null values
data = [("Alice", [34]), ("Bob", None), ("Catherine", [28]), ("David", None)]
schema = StructType([
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("age", type_)
])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

df = df.withColumn('age', F.col('age').cast('string')) \
  .fillna('[]', subset=['age']) \
  .withColumn('age', from_json(col('age'), schema=type_))

# Show the updated DataFrame
df.show()
```